# can i use both jdbcTemplet as well as hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

can i use both  jdbcTemplet as well as hibernate. because there are very complex joins in my application and that can be done easily with jdbc templete...and hibernate give ease on insert update and delete...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use them together.  However there's a little catch. If you want changes made in one available in the other, you should make sure they're using the same transaction manager.  JDBCTemplate will work the with the hibernate transaction manager.